# How to design database for product sets/packs

Tags: database-design, inventory-management

I am designing a database for inventory system. My client sells products in two different ways:

1. As a whole set (like set of 8 parts in a bath fittings pack)
2. Any of these parts can be sold separately

If one or any number of parts has been sold, they need a report to know how many complete sets altogether they have in stock.

For example:

If `part-a`, `part-b`, `part-c` and `part-d` have been sold from one pack and
`part-e`, `part-f`, `part-g` and `part-h` have been sold from another pack then
stock status report should be showing `ONE COMPLETE PACK` with 8 parts.

I have tried to do this by dividing products in category and sub-category, but cannot get stock status report accurately.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is often known as a ["Bill of materials"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_of_materials).

There are several ways of implementing this in a database - [here](http://www.tdan.com/view-special-features/5400/)'s a decent overview.